# $str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7"; How to get the sum of values?

Tags: php, string, sum, delimited

I was asked this question in a PHP test,

**Question:** How to get the sum of values?

```
$str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
```

**My Solution was:**

```
// Splitting numbers in array and adding them up
$str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
$num_array = explode(',', $str);

$str = 0;
foreach($num_array as $num) {
    $str+=$num;
}
echo $str;
```

I was told that my solution is BAD, is it BAD? Can anyone please tell why is it BAD? And any better/best solutions?

Thanks, in advance

Comment: I would approach it the same way. But your naming is not ideal. `$str = 0;` should be named something else. Like: `$sum = 0;` Also like others have said PHP has a build in function to sum up array values.

Comment: If someone tells you the solution is bad but refuses to tell you _why_ it is bad, that's pretty sad. At any rate, if you are looking for qualitative judgements on your code and suggestions for improvements, you might want to try codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your solution is correct, but they might be expecting optimized or efficient or smallest code. May be like this:

```
$str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
echo array_sum(explode(',', $str));
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `array_sum(explode(",",$yourarray))` after exploding the string rather than looping array . this would be more efficient.